# Unable to delete all current elements of core data database

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I am trying to delete all the data in my core data database but it is throwing up an error and is not affecting the SQLite database at all.

```
if self.userCredentials.count > 0 {
        for loopIndex in 0 ... self.userCredentials.count - 1 {
                self.context.delete(self.userCredentials[loopIndex])
                self.userCredentials.remove(at: loopIndex)
        }
        self.saveLogin()
}

func saveLogin() {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print ("Context saved successfully")
        }
        catch {
            print ("Error saving items \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Fatal Error: Index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
for userCredential in userCredentials {
    context.delete(userCredential)
}

saveLogin()
```

The problem with your code is that you loop the amount of times of elements that variable userCredentials holds. That is an immutable value which won't be changed and it initialized before it looped even once.

You are accessing the index of an array based on the index. That's not wrong, but shouldn't be done in cases in which a simple for-in (see code above) is sufficient.

After that, you manipulate the element count by removing an element. That doesn't effect the immutable element count that I stated above. Because of that, soon or later you get an index out of bounds exception. You should try to search for what that exactly is, you try to access an element in a list which does not exists.